# NextJS - getStaticPaths check for new pages

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I use `getStaticPaths` to prerender all dynamic pages. I was wondering how can I fetch all pages every x seconds?

[image]

Comment: Provide a screenshot or sandbox link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mike `getStaticPaths` pre-renders all the paths only at build time.
You can use `fallback` prop to have fallback option while page is building.
Refer this [when is fallback useful](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#when-is-fallback-true-useful)

`getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` is all about pre rendering pages and using static pages. If you want to have always upto date content then use `getServerSideProps` instead.

In addition, in your code I see you are already using `revalidate` prop in getStaticProps which helps you to revalidate them every 60 seconds, I believe should serve your purpose.